# pyparsing - parse simple line

Tags: pyparsing

I'm scratching my head on how to completely parse this line,
I'm having trouble with the '( 4801)' part, every other elements are being grabbed OK.

```
# MAIN_PROG     ( 4801) Generated at 2010-01-25 06:55:00
```

This is what I have so far

```
from pyparsing import nums, Word, Optional, Suppress, OneOrMore, Group, Combine, ParseException

unparsed_log_data = "# MAIN_PROG ( 4801) Generated at 2010-01-25 06:55:00.007    Type:  Periodic"

binary_name = "# MAIN_PROG"
pid = Literal("(" + nums + ")")
report_id = Combine(Suppress(binary_name) + pid)

year = Word(nums, max=4)
month = Word(nums, max=2)
day = Word(nums, max=2)
yearly_day = Combine(year + "-" + month + "-" + day)

clock24h = Combine(Word(nums, max=2) + ":" + Word(nums, max=2) + ":" + Word(nums, max=2) + Suppress("."))
timestamp = Combine(yearly_day + White(' ') + clock24h).setResultsName("timestamp")

time_bnf = report_id + Suppress("Generated at") + timestamp

time_bnf.searchString(unparsed_log_data)
```

**EDIT:**
Paul, if you have the patience,
how would I filter

```
unparsed_log_data = 
"""  
# MAIN_PROG     ( 4801) Generated at 2010-01-25 06:55:00
bla bla bla   
multi line garbage  
bla bla  
Efficiency       |       38       38 100 |   3497061    3497081  99 |  
more garbage
"""

time_bnf = report_id + Suppress("Generated at") + timestamp  
partial_report_ignore = Suppress(SkipTo("Efficiency"))  

efficiency_bnf = Suppress("|") + integer.setResultsName("Efficiency") + Suppress(integer) + integer.setResultsName("EfficiencyPercent")
```

Both 
efficiency_bnf.searchString(unparsed_log_data) and 
report_and_effic.searchString(unparsed_log_data)
return data as expected,
but if I try

report_and_effic = report_bnf + partial_report_ignore + efficiency_bnf

report_and_effic.searchString(unparsed_log_data)
returns ([], {})

**EDIT2:**
one should read in the code,
partial_report_ignore = Suppress(SkipTo("Efficiency", **include=True**))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pid = Literal("(" + nums + ")")
```

should be

```
pid = "(" + Word(nums) + ")"
```

Pyparsing allows you to add strings to expression objects using '+', like:

```
expr + "some string"
```

Which gets interpreted as:

```
expr + Literal("some string")
```

You wrote `Literal("(" + nums + ")")`.  nums is the string "0123456789", to be used as part of creating Word's, like `Word(nums)`.  So what you were trying to match was not "left-paren followed by a word composed of nums followed by right-paren", you were trying to match the literal string "(0123456789)".

Comment: Makes sense, just like everything else in pyparsing :)
Your module is awesome! Thanks Paul

Comment: Found what I was looking for in my EDIT.
Just had to add 'include=True' to the SkipTo.

Comment: That's great, and thanks for the kind words! Also, I'm glad to see you are using results names, let me encourage you to use their short form, `integer("efficiency")` vs. `integer.setResultsName("efficiency")` - it will keep your parser definition code more readable.

Comment: Thanks Paul. Using short form now !